# Jquery replace link with new value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I am reading data from a database and adding each link in a new table row.
I wrote a jquery function to replace the href of the link with a new value, but it is not working.

Also I have to mention that each time a new link is added to the table, I want the replacement to be done instantly, without click event or something.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").show(function() {
    var before = $(this).href;
    var replacewith = "https://www.google.com"
    var after = before.replace(before, replacewith);
    $(this).attr("href", after);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="aaa">Link1</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Error here `$(this).href;`. Why not just `$('.aaa').attr('href', 'google.com');`

Comment: You should add an `id` attribute to your link because `$("a")` will get all page links..

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix it - $(this).href should be $(this).attr("href") or $(this).prop("href") or just this.href - I vote to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: @Tushar just to point out, there is no class assign to hyperlink. [provided in the question ]. so may be `$('.aaa')` is not going to work.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Uh-oh! Wrong selector. I thought it is class. Need coffee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has unnecessary lines. However fix is done

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").show(function () {
            var before = $(this).attr('href'); 
            var replacewith = "https://www.google.com";
            var after = before.replace(before, replacewith);
            $(this).attr("href", after);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

[*edited: removed original comment for clarity*]

See the second comment for answer.

Comment: nope :) you're wrong. Did you run an example before posting an answer?
Not my downvote. Don't blame me :)

Comment: $(this).href should be $(this).attr("href") or $(this).prop("href") or just this.href